# Нет доступа к унаследованным членам, функциям?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, полиморфизм

Имеется класс базовый, абстрактный, с определенными полями и несколькими ф-ми, имеется наследник данного класса, у класса наследника может быть неограниченное количество потомков, при этом в наследуемом классе от абстрактного есть доступ к полям и методам базового класса, а у потомков наследника нет к ним доступа.

Как мне получить к ним доступ без перегрузки первоначальных функций, ведь они являются потомками?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<crystalball on>`

Потому что Вы используете `private` наследование.

`</crystalball off>`

Comment: Ой, точно, надо же `public` при наследовании дописывать, это все от си шарпа привычка не указывать.

Comment: используйте struct)

Comment: Весь мозг уже сломал думаю что не так